# Apache POI function to update column based on other column action

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

Need a help in Apache POI code.

I have excel with 4 columns as ID,FirstName,LastName,IsCapable, On column FirstName any value update happens then IsCapable column value should be updated as TRUE.

Attached the sheet screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7giKO.png)

Expectation is from the sheet column B row 3 if i change any value from "Shivu" to "Shivuuu" then IsCapable column value should be automatically update as TRUE using Apache POI.